# Unable to update the deployment containers ports name on redeployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

What happened:
managementPort is provided by default while applying the k8s manifest.

"mng-mytest" is the name alias for containerPort in deployment manifest.
ports:

- containerPort: 9095
  name: mng-mytest

Recently we changed the value of default management port, however for existing deployments that are running
when redeployed the changes of new default mgmt port while getting applied fails with this issue,

The Deployment "mytestservice-deployment" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[2].name: Duplicate value: "mng-mytest"

"mng-mytest" is the name alias for containerPort in deployment manifest.
ports:

- containerPort: 9090
  name: mng-mytest

What you expected to happen:
The new port value should get applied.

How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):
First, add a port name and value to the containerPort section of the deployment manifest
then deploy.
Second, change the value of the containerPort but keep the name same then redeploy on top of above existing running deployment.

Comment: Did you delete the old deployment? Because the message is saying that the metadata names are duplicated, which makes sense. Is it a test or a production application? If it is a test, I would recommend deleting the old deployment/service/replicaset and etc.

Comment: When you say "change" and "deploy", what commands exactly are you running?